# Java - Add element to empty set (immutable)

Tags: java, methods, data-structures, set, immutability

I've been working on trying to implement an immutable set from scratch, so I'm not using HashSet or java.util.Set

I have this method in my Empty class to add an element to an empty set:

```
public Set<T> add(T x) {
  return new Element<T>(x, new Empty<T>());
}
```

And in another class called Element, I have the following constructor:

```
     public Element(T element, Empty<T> empty) {
     assert(element != null);
     assert(empty != null);

     this.element = element;
     this.set = empty;
   }
```

EDIT: here is my other Element constructor used for adding an element to a set.

```
public Element(T x, Set<T> set) {
            this.element = x;
            this.set = set;
        }
```

But when I try to add an element it fails and the set is still empty.
I've used a similar code when creating an immutable Binary Search Tree and it worked fine so I assumed that I could do the same but for an immutable Set.

I was just wondering if the problem was with my add method or my constructor

Thank you

---

The size method:
for the Empty class

```
/**
     * returns number of elements in the set
     * @return size  - number of elements in the set
     */
    public int size(){
        return -1;
        }
```

for the element class:

```
   @Override
        public int size() {
            if (set.isEmpty() == true) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return set.toList().size();
            }
        }
```

the toList() method:

```
@Override
    public List<T> toList() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < set.size(); i++){
            list.set(i, element);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

reading over this part I realise that the problem with returning the size may be from the toList method I wrote, but I don't think that should have an effect on adding an element to the set?

toString - Element Class:

```
 @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Set = [" + set + "]";
        }
```

toString - Empty class:

```
public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
```

And the JUnit Test for Add:
EDIT: realised that the set was immutable and so tried to make a new set that was equal to the empty set with the added value - to store the change but kept getting the same NullPointerException error.

```
 @Test
        public final void testAdd() {
            Set<Integer> set1;
            set1 = set.add(1);
            int i = 20;
            set.add(i);

            assertSame("Last element should be the newly added name object", i, set.toList().get(set.size()-1));
            assertEquals("Set size should be two", 2, set.size());
        }
```

The assertSame gives a NullPointerException (so I'm guessing this means that the add didn't work and the set is still empty); and if I comment it out to test the next line the assertEquals says that set.size() is -1 (empty)

Comment: There's not enough context here. "It fails" in what way? Compile error? Runtime exception? Unexpected behavior? If the latter, what constitutes expected behavior, and what did you observe? When you say "the set is still empty", how are you checking?

Comment: Apologies, I would say unexpected behaviour. I have an app called DemoSet and a JUnit Test that test the method and each time I run them after adding an element they both return that the size of the set is -1 (empty), instead of the size of the set and output "Set = []" from a toString method I wrote further down in my code, instead of "Set = [1,2,3,4,5]"

Comment: You haven't posted any unit test, size method or toString method. Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: I've made the edit with the unit test and the requested methods - I hope this can give a better insight into my thinking

Comment: Both `size()` and `toString()` are ignoring `element`. Why?

Comment: Do you mean by not having "element" as an argument/parameter? Or not in the code within the method? I thought I didn't need to pass any parameters to find the size or to write out a String. And as to why it is not in the code within the method - it was because I thought I needed to use the set as a whole

Comment: I'm referring to the code in the methods. As I understand it, "the set as a whole" is comprised of two parts: the current element, and a pointer to the rest of the set. You would need to factor in both. To put it differently, why would you be surprised that `set.isEmpty()` when you clearly assigned `set` to `new Empty<T>()`?

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense now. I know that by setting it to new Empty<T>() it's creating a new empty set, but after adding an element, it should have returned a new set with an element in as specified by the Element class. Or is it because it is an immutable set that once I've initialised the set, I can make changes (e.g. add an element) but the changes aren't permanent (so by trying to determine whether or not the set is empty it's using the old set and not the new updated set)?

Comment: The point of an immutable structure is that `set` is never modified. It's just a chain of references. I'm not sure why I need to explain your own code to you.

Comment: I know what an immutable data structure is; as I said in the original post, I had previously written an immutable binary search tree in a similar manner and didn't have this issue. I was merely looking for some assistance.  My current edit to the JUnit test shows that I do, I simply forgot to account for the immutability when adding a new element -  I was just asking for confirmation that this was the reason why it wasn't returning anything.

Comment: I am confused: is `Element` a `Set`? Is `Empty` a `Set`? Why constructor of `Element` is taking an `Empty` but not a `Set` as 2nd argument? and why you are checking `i != '\0'` in your `toList` for loop?

Comment: for NPE in test, it is obvious: ` Set<Integer> set1; set1 = set.add(1);` `set1` is not pointing to anything.  Learn to use an IDE and Debugger.  I believe you should be able to find almost all problems with basic debugging technique

Comment: @AdrianShum yes, Element and Empty are both sets. That is only one constructor of element, I have another constructor in my code (not written above) that takes a second argument that is set (I'll add it in an edit so you can see) - I'm currently trying to figure out why it won't allow me to add an element to an empty set, before trying to make the next constructor work. And as for why I was checking i != '\0', I realise now that I should have been checking i < set.size() instead as that doesn't make sense. Edits have been made to correct this.

Comment: I have a variable called set declared outside the tests - I didn't put the whole test here as I thought it would be too long of a question, so I thought set1 would be pointing to that, but thank you I will go and brush up on my debugging technique

Comment: for whatever you quoted it doesn't quite make sense.  The implementation of `size()` etc seems all wrong.  You don't need an extra ctor for `Element` if `Empty` is a `Set`.  Though it is off topics of SO, I will write some code to demonstrate how it should look like as I think it is quite interesting topic to me

Comment: your changes makes the code even worse: in order to find the `size()`, you need to call `toList()` to construct the list.  However when you are calling `toList()`, you can in turns calling `size()`. Never-ending recusion

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything in your existing code is flawed.  Your `Element`'s ctor does not make sense, `size()` and `toList()` are implemented in weird way, even the unit test is flawed in basic Java.

Some pseudo code

```
interface Set<T> {
  Set<T> add(T v);
  int size();
  boolean contains(T v);
}

class Element<T> extends Set<T> {
  T value;
  Set<T> next;
  public Element<T>(T element, Set<T> next) {...}

  public Set<T> add(T value) {
    if contains(value) { // already in set
      return this;
    }
    return new Element(value, this);
  }
  public int size() {
    return next.size() + 1;
  }
  public boolean contains(T value) {
    return (this.value.equals(value) || next.contains(value));
  }
}

public class Empty<T> extends Set<T> {

  public Set<T> add(T value) {
    return new Element(value, this);
  }
  public int size() {
    return 0;  // come on! 0 means empty, not -1!
  }
  public boolean contains(T value) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do have a set interface already, I have an abstract class that implements set, I'll put it in an answer below and in regards to return -1; I was taught that -1 represents an empty set which is why I used it, but like I said, I'll put my code in an answer below for a clearer view

Comment: I assume you do have the interface, I am just making that up as something sensible to demonstrate the idea.  I dunno why -1 means an empty set. What does 0 means then?  And, you shouldn't put your code in an answer unless it is an answer.  This answer is not aimed as a piece of code that you can copy and paste.  It demonstrate the idea to you and show how weird your existing code is

Comment: Ah ok. I was taught that 0 meant false, 1 meant true and -1 represented an empty. Oh, ok. I never intended to copy and paste your or anyone else's code, I just needed clarification as to why it was returning an empty set despite having used code near identical to it for a binary search tree (and a stack) and not having this issue. The thing is, structurally, the example you gave and the code I have is also near identical, I guess it's just my implementation within the methods, which I am by no means asking you to write for me. I will go back and check over my code once more. Thank you

Comment: Well, I don't know how your "almost identical binary tree" code will work if you are checking `'\0'` in for loop, and access uninitialized variable in unit test

Comment: and, I don't know where does your "0 meant false, 1 meant true and -1 represented an empty" come from.  In Java, `false` means false, `true` means true.  Empty is not part of a boolean. If you are in C/C++ etc, 0 means false, and *non-zero* means true

Comment: Firstly, the main focus of the question was NOT the toList() method. If you fully read the original question, I stated that I KNEW the toList() method didn't work properly but that it shouldn't have any effect on what I WAS focusing on (the add method). THAT is the bit that is near identical to my old BST code, which works perfectly fine and adds elements as expected. But for some reason isn't producing the right outcome when used in a set.

Comment: Furthermore, I stated that I was taught that -1 represented empty; however, this may just be for determining the depth of a BST, I just assumed that depth represented the same thing as size for a set.

Answer (score -1):

Having reviewed my code, I realised where I was making the mistake.

Aside from the messy code in other areas, the add(T x) method was not working as expected due to the fact that I did not import the Empty or Element class to the Demo set or the JUnit test and, as mentioned by @shmosel, my toString method wasn't working properly because I did not include the element field and so was not going to output anything.

The following is my Demo code showing how I've added the import line. Furthermore, the constructor for Element works fine too. Again, I just needed to import the class for an Empty set for it to work.

```
 package immutable.set;

    import immutable.set.Empty;

    public class DemoSet {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Set<Integer> set, set1, set2;

            set = new Empty<Integer>();
            System.out.println(set.isEmpty());

            set1 = set.add(1).add(2);
            set2 = set.add(3);

            System.out.println(set1.toString());
            System.out.println(set1.isEmpty());
            System.out.println(set2.toString());
            System.out.println(set2.isEmpty());

        }

    }
```

And it does print out the expected outcome.

Thank you for you help everyone.

Comment: No, your explanation is wrong.  Simply adding imports will not do any difference.  As I have said in the comment, and in my answer, the problem of your NPE in your unit test is that you haven't initialized your reference to `Set`.  It is pointing to null hence giving you NPE.  In this answer, you fixed that (`set = new Empty<Integer>();`)